# ng-repeat data in 3 column layout

Tags: angularjs, gridview, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-grid

I have an array and i am iterating through it using ng-repeat but I need to display it on UI in a 3 column layout properly aligned like what we have in ecommerce websites, how can i do that?

I am using below but it shows proper for 1 row and only 1 item in another and scattered un evenly.

```
 <div class="span_2">
             <div class="row col-md-3 col_1_of_single1 span_1_of_single1" data-ng-repeat="product in products">
                <a href="#/productDetail">
                 <img src="{{product.productImageLargeURL}}" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                 <h3>{{product.productName}}</h3>
                 <!--<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure</p>-->
                 <h4>Rs. {{product.productPrice}}</h4>
                 </a>  
              </div>


              <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Use `track by $index` wherever there is `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

because you want to each row have 3 `col` so you should put `row` class on `ng-repeat` and in each repeat content crate your layout. so i put `col-md-4` in inner `DIV` for this. may be help you.

```
 <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="product in products">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col_1_of_single1 span_1_of_single1">
               <a href="#/productDetail">
                 <img src="{{product.productImageLargeURL}}" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                 <h3>{{product.productName}}</h3>
                 <!--<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure</p>-->
                <h4>Rs. {{product.productPrice}}</h4>
                </a>  
          </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: *"try like this"* isn't a meaningful answer explanation

Comment: Use `track by $index` wherever there is `ng-repeat`

Comment: @SSH - it is only displying in 1 column,

Comment: what are these classes `span_1_of_single1` and `col_1_of_single1`?